# Weird behavior while weblogic bootup

Tags: weblogic, port, weblogic12c

I am trying to boot weblogic (`12c`) .

I am facing a weird problem , while the weblogic server starts ,It tries to listen to port which is free.

But it gives the error that the port is in use(as shown in the first line of logs below),but then suddenly in the next line it starts listening the port. Any idea why this kind of behavior ?

```
<Jul 24, 2013 3:25:20 PM IST> <Error> <Server> <BEA-002606> <The server is unable to create a server socket for listening on channel "Default". The address 10.19.218.207 might be incorrect or another process is using port 12110: java.net.BindException: Address already in use>
<Jul 24, 2013 3:25:20 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:12110 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
<Jul 24, 2013 3:25:20 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:fe8a:29cc:12110 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
<Jul 24, 2013 3:25:20 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:12110 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
```

Comment: It looks like your problem is: not being able to bind to `10.19.218.207`, and not the port. Is this address correct?

Comment: Yes, the address here is correct.IF the address was wrong,it would have failed to boot right ?

Comment: It looks like it booted on localhost and not `10.19.218.207` as Viccari said. Either way, you can try and change the IP or the port in the admin console or by editing config.xml to see what the problem is.